# What is the need of checking long Type to null in grails

Tags: grails

When i generate the Views of the Domain, gsp page creates the Following stuff automatically.

```
 <g:if test="${dataArchivingInstance?.id != null}">  
      <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${dataArchivingInstance?.id}"/>  
 </g:if>
```

dataArchivingInstance.id is of long type. Now What is the need of checking long Type to null? Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if it's null, you don't need to make this hidden field.

UPD: It's `Long` (Object) type, not `long` (primitive), and it can be `null`

Comment: long type variable has default value to 0. Then What is the need of checking long Type to null instread 0.

Comment: Long is an Object, not a primitive number and therefore can be null